# how to execute some code before alert appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div by clicking on it and AFTER the div is hidden - an alert should appears.

Problem - the alert appears BEFORE the div is hidden.

```js
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
  alert('LOREM IS HIDDEN');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lorem'>LOREM</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `alert`. It has weird interactions with the control flow, so it's not good as a debugging tool. It's also bad as a UI tool because it looks generic and probably doesn't tie up with the design and/or intention of the message.

Comment: Anyway, this works in FF but the behaviour you see is present in Chrome. This is due to the weird interaction with the control flow I mentioned - it's inconsistent. With Chrome, the alert shows and blocks the UI thread until the alert is dismissed but since it's fired in the same event loop as hiding the div, it also blocks that. Hence the behaviour you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's `.hide` offers a [callback](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete) for when the element has disappeared.

```js
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide(function() {
    alert('LOREM IS HIDDEN');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lorem'>LOREM</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Using setTimeout will give you result you want

```
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
  setTimeout(function(){alert('LOREM IS HIDDEN')} , 0);
})
```

2.You can also use callback as second parameter of hide function
https://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide(function() {
    alert('LOREM IS HIDDEN'););
})
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){alert('LOREM IS HIDDEN')} , 0);` also a bit shorter `setTimeout(alert, 0, 'LOREM IS HIDDEN');`